# При открытии модального окна фон затемняется по все странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, всплывающее-окно

Всем привет! такая проблема - при запуске модального окна фон затемняется на всей странице и не возвращается в исходное состоянии при нажатии на кнопку закрытия. Что может быть не так?

```js
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline'
    });
```

```css
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 25px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <a class="popup-modal btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#modal-event">Заказать</a>

<div id="modal-event" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  <h1>Форма по ивентам</h1>
  [contact-form-7 id="3155" title="Форма по ивентам"]
  <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Закрыть</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Для ответа нужен JS-код и CSS-стили.

Comment: Скорее всего я уже понял - конфликт с js скриптом magnific popup

Comment: Если понятно и проблема решена - закройте вопрос.

Comment: а как можно реализовать модальное окно на magnific popup

Comment: Ищите в документации. Тут помогают, а не делают за автора. Если нужно чтобы сделали - есть фриланс-биржи.

Comment: здесь уже все расписано как подключить этот плагин http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/. Покажите свой код и что у вас не получается?

Comment: изменил в первом сообщении - темный фон и форма на весь экран

Comment: вроде решил - спасибо за попытку помощи

Comment: @TheDoctor: главная польза от Stack Overflow в том, что кроме (одного) автора вопроса, могут быть ещё (возможно многочисленные) будущие посетители из гугла, которым всё равно сколько усилий приложил автор, если на их вопрос присутствует хороший ответ. Поэтому не нужно на фриланс-биржи отправлять, *если сам вопрос может быть полезен и другим людям*. См. [Работа за автора на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: Эмн, нет. Во-первых, автор дал мало сведений для решения задачи, во-вторых, можно помочь, даже чуть раздвинуть понятие "помощи" (от себя написать что-то), но только когда ест каркас и хорошая тема.